# Issues with the filter command in R studio

Tags: r

trying to filter from the gapminder dataset and I am getting the error message:

> china <- gapminder %>% filter(country == "China")
> Error in filter(., country == "China") : object 'country' not found

the code i used was:   `china <- gapminder %>% filter(country == "China")`

I recently updated my Rstudio to Version 1.4.1717 and R to 4.1.0.
I usually use Rstudio so i'm not sure if the error is due to something I don't understand about this new version.
Is this something to do with the version of R Studio I'm using?

I would be grateful for any advice as it's driving me a bit crazy.

Comment: What does `names(gapminder)` return? What does `environment(filter)` return?

Comment: Use dplyr::filter(country == "China"). You're probably using stats::filter by mistake

Comment: @BillO'Brien If dplyr isn't loaded I would have expected the error on the `%>%`, I guess it's possible a different package has loaded the pipe operator.

Comment: What `library()` calls have you run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to be explicit with some functions like `filter`. You are likely getting an error, because it is using `stats::filter` rather than the one from `dplyr`.

```
gapminder %>% stats::filter(country == "China")
```

> Error in stats::filter(., country == "China") :    object 'country'
> not found

However, if you use `dplyr` explicitly, then it works.

```
library(dplyr)

gapminder %>% dplyr::filter(country == "China")
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  country continent  year lifeExp       pop gdpPercap
  <fct>   <fct>     <int>   <dbl>     <int>     <dbl>
1 China   Asia       1952    44   556263527      400.
2 China   Asia       1957    50.5 637408000      576.
3 China   Asia       1962    44.5 665770000      488.
4 China   Asia       1967    58.4 754550000      613.
5 China   Asia       1972    63.1 862030000      677.
6 China   Asia       1977    64.0 943455000      741.
```

Comment: Any guessing what package might have loaded `%>%`? If dplyr wasn't loaded I would have expected the error on the `%>%` I'm not sure how the stats::filter would be found first otherwise.

Comment: So, it looks like if you have loaded `tidyr` and have not loaded `dplyr`, then `%>%` works fine. If you use `gapminder %>% filter(country == "China")`, then R seems to default to `stats::filter`. But once you load `dplyr` (or `plotly`), then it defaults to `dplyr` when using `filter`.

Comment: what does stats::filter do?

Comment: It "applies linear filtering to a univariate time series or to each series separately of a multivariate time series." You can read more in the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/filter.html) for `stats::filter`.